# LibreOffice creates tmp file every save

Tags: libreoffice, temporary-files

When opening a LibreOffice document on a remote share, the title bar says "Title.ods (remote)", and whenever I save the document a new temporary file is created, with a name like `~gvfry9s.tmp`.

I cannot delete these files.

How do I prevent LibreOffice making these files? I am using Fedora 27, LibreOffice 5.4.4.1.

When mounting the share using `mount`, I do not have this problem.